# I am getting multivaluedictkeyerror while getting values from the form

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

I wanted some details to update in user details model but when I try to read value from the request
it show the **multivaluedictkeyerror**.

**error images**
[image: error image 1]

[image: error image 2]

**views.py**

```py
@csrf_exempt
def updateuser(request):
   myuser=request.user
   obj=User.objects.get(id=myuser.id)
   if request.method == 'POST':
      p=request.POST['phone']
      a=request.POST['add']
      e=request.POST['edu']
      em=request.POST['email']
      c=request.POST['country']
      s=request.POST['state']
      userdetails.objects.create(
          user=obj, phone=p, address=a,
          edu=e, country=c, state=s
          )
    return render(request,'profile.html')
```

**html code**

```html
<form action="updateuser" method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="labels">PhoneNumber</label>
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder={{uobj1.phone}} name="phone" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="labels">Address</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={{uobj1.address}} name="add" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="labels">Email ID</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder={{uobj.email}} name="email" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label class="labels">Education</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={{uobj1.edu}} name="edu" required>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label class="labels">Country</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={{uobj1.country}} name="country" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <label class="labels">State/Region</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder={{uobj1.state}} name="state" required>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="mt-5 text-center">
     <button class="btn btn-primary profile-button" type="submit">Save Profile</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

**app urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
path('index',views.home,name='index'),
path('profile',views.profile),
path('logdetails',views.checklogin),
path('login',views.ulogin,name='ulogin'),
path('lout',views.lout),
path('regdetails',views.usersave),
path('viewpro',views.viewpro),
path('setbid',views.setbid,name='setbid'),
path('products',views.productlist),
path('updateuser',views.updateuser)
]
```

i have added the urls.py file but i dont see any error in this everything works fine only update user shows that error

Comment: i tried using admin account in my webpage not on django administration. on my web page if i add details using admin login id and pass it works. but if i try to use another user 's id pass to add details in my webpage it shows like this  multivaluedictkeyerror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at last i have luckily got Answer it was an silly answer but it worked for me..

just give the **name** attribute in input fields in before placeholder.

example:
**old code**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={{uobj1.country}} name="country" required>
```

**updated code**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="country" placeholder={{uobj1.country}} required>
```

Answer (score 0):

action in `<form action="updateuser" method="POST">`  should be a url pattern or name like `action = {% url 'appname : updateuser' %}`

Comment: i have tried it but not working it shows ** NoReverseMatch at /auction/profile Reverse for 'updateuser' not found. 'updateuser' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**

Answer (score 0):

Multivalue Key error happens when the requested value is not receiving to the backend. Make sure you are using the correct name in the HTML tag as in request.post['name']. if not working try using

```
request.POST.get('name')
```

Also, put form action like this

```
<form action={% url 'url-name' %}>
```

Comment: i have tried it but not working **NoReverseMatch at /auction/profile
Reverse for 'updateuser' not found. 'updateuser' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**

Comment: check you have given valid url name and view name is correct.

Comment: Yes that was correct as I have given the code above

Comment: @Lakshmanan Please show your urls.py file

Comment: i have added the urls.py

Comment: @Lakshmanan You haven't given url name for updateuser. path('updateuser', views.updateuser, name='updateuser')

Comment: i have tried by giving name but it does'nt worked same error

Comment: @Lakshmanan Reverse Noreverse match found error occurs when you haven't given valid url. Please double check you have given everything correctly. Its just a simple error. watch a video on creating urls and form submission.